# How do you get the HTML tag of the control in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet

How do I get the HTML tag of a Locator?

With the following HTML element:

```
<textarea id="AnySpecialInstructions" name="AnySpecialInstructions" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

If I get it by the locator of

```
var locator = Page.Locator("id=AnySpecialInstructions");
```

How would would you get the HTML tag of textarea?

Comment: Just to clarify you want `textarea` in your locator variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get `textarea` into your variable **locator**, you can do this:

```cs
var locator = await page.EvaluateAsync<string>("document.querySelector('#AnySpecialInstructions').tagName")
```